# align div content in the middle/center?

Tags: css, html

hi can someone please help me with this because i have tried everything.

i am trying to align the content of  center inside of my div called "wrapper".

whatever i do the content just will not align center of the page. hope someone can help me thanks.

css:

```
body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        font-size:medium; 
        color:#3f3f3f; 
        background:#26265d; 
        padding:0; 
        margin:0;
        text-align:center;
    }

.wrapper {width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:auto; display:block; text-align:center;
     position:relative; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;


}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php include("includes/mod_home/mod_newest.php"); ?>
</div>
```

php page:

```
<?php
        $newest_set = get_newest_member();
        $newest_count = mysql_num_rows($newest_set);
        while ($newest = mysql_fetch_array($newest_set)) {
        $strn = "".$newest['display_name']."";
        $max = 13;
        if(strlen($strn) > $max) {
        $strn = substr($strn, 0, $max) . '...'; } 
$photo = "../data/photos/{$newest['id']}/_default.jpg";

if (!file_exists($photo)) {
    $photo = "../data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}

            echo"
            <div class=\"mod_newest_image\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$newest['id']}\"><img width=95px src=\"".$photo."\"/></a>

            </div>";

    }
    ?>


<style>

.new_text{
    color:#373775;
    position:absolute;
}
.mod_newest_image img{
    border:2px solid #6f6f6f;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
    width:95px;
    height:120px;
    display:block;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin:3px;

 }
</style>
```

Comment: this is a pure CSS-question, remove the php tag to get more answers

Comment: Do not post PHP code but the generated output. CSS doesn't apply on PHP code.

Comment: You should spend some more time on learning and practicing the basics.

Comment: your wrapper already in the center. IF images inside wrapper that was generated by php are not in center, its because its floating left. check css in your php as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper can't have a width of 100% if you are trying to center it with margin: 0 auto; You need to give the wrapper a value less than 100% for it to work.

```
.wrapper {width:1000px; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: but im trying to make a mobile site and so i want the width to be a percentage so taht

Comment: Then go ahead and put in a percentage. Even a 90% would be centered. The idea is that the browser can't center something that is taking up the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

`wrapper need size`, don't need `position:relative`;

if your image size is not the same as wrapper. you may need add `margin: 0 auto;` to align center inside of wraper